# Veins and Artery throwing errors after downgrading Omnet++ back to 5.1.1

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I recently have downgraded Omnet++ from version 5.2 back to version 5.1.1 because of the newer one not working with the Artery Extension for Veins. 
After a clean make of 5.1.1 and also a clean recompile of Artery both the example scenario of Artery and that of Veins immediately throw error messages after starting.

Here is the error that Veins throws:

```
<!> (omnetpp::cGroupFigure)RSUExampleScenario.canvas.rootFigure: removeFigure(): Figure is not a child -- in module (Veins::AnnotationManager) RSUExampleScenario.annotations (id=3), during network initialization
```

Artery will build but always crashes at Event 14:

```
<!> Invalid High Frequency CAM: Latitude: constraint failed (/home/wiconlab/Car2x/artery-master/extern/vanetza/vanetza/asn1/gen/Latitude.c:30) -- in module (artery::VehicleMiddleware) World.node[1].appl.middleware (id=15), at t=0.260276337038s, event #14
```

Additional information about libraries, versions, OS etc:
Ubuntu 16.04
Omnet++ 5.1.1
Veins 4.6
Boost 1.58
cryptopp 5.6.4
geographic-lib 1.49
cmake 3.9.6

Comment: Just so I understand this correctly: you are using both Artery and Veins. Both worked with OMNeT 5.1.1. Both failed to work on OMNeT 5.2. After downgrading to OMNeT 5.1.1, neither started working again?

Comment: Any chance that paths are messed up due to the compilation for another OMNeT++ version? I don't know about Artery and Veins, maybe some configure scripts that you need to re-run?

Comment: For the Artery error: can you check whether `VANETZA_ASN1_WITH_ASN1C`  is set to `ON` or `OFF`? I would suggest to turn it `OFF` if it is currently `ON`

Comment: What also can be a problem: If SUMO not provides correct coordinates. Are you sure you have compiled SUMO with all needed libs? Can you run the configure script of SUMO again and check if `PROJ` and `GDAL` are activated? If not, SUMO may not provide correct latitudes and longitudes.

Comment: @ChristophSommer: I installed it with OMNeT 5.2. first, then downgraded. Both Veins and Artery have yet to run withour Error on this machine. I have it up and running on another ubuntu System however.

Comment: @Ventu: `VANETZA_ASN1_WITH_ASN1C` is set to `OFF`. `PROJ` was missing. I fixed that, rebuilt Sumo and after that reconfigured and rebuilt Artery, including a rebuild of Inet, Veins and Vanetza. Both Errors still persist.

Comment: @M.Hardt can you check if SUMO now provides correct coordinates? At first you can look if longitude and latitude are showing up at the lower right corner of the SUMO gui when running an scenario. If there are only X and Y coordinates showing up, then SUMO might not provide proper longitude and latitude.

Comment: @Ventu The Sumo GUI indeed only shows x/y-coordinates in the lower left corner.

Comment: make that the right corner...

Comment: @M.Hardt this means, that SUMO still not provides the real coordinates. Hence, the coordinates wich should be written in the CAM are wrong. I think, Arterien will work without errors if you fix the SUMO problem.

Comment: @Ventu Something is still wrong with `PROJ`. I downloaded the source (version 4.9.3) and ran `./configure` and `make`. The Sumo configuration worked after that and `PROJ` is no longer shown as missing. Yet when I type `proj` in the terminal, it gives me the following error Message: `proj: error while loading shared libraries: libproj.so.12: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`.

Comment: proj is now working fine. However there are still some projection options missing in netconvert (specifically  --proj.plain-geo) and SUMO still doesn't provide geo coordinates. I have honestly no ideas left...

Comment: @M.Hard which SUMO map are you using? I'm not an SUMO expert, so I'm not sure if I can help with the SUMO problem.

Comment: @Ventu The Sumo problem is now solved and with it the Error that Artery threw. Thanks very much for the help. The error in Veins however still occurs.