# Artery error: Invalid High Frequency CAM: Lattitude

Tags: omnet++, sumo, plexe-veins

Currently, I am getting used to Artery to simulate platoons based on the ETSI standard. I finished installing and setting up Artery on my VMWare Ubuntu 20.04.

However, when running Artery as instructed in [here](http://artery.v2x-research.eu/install/), I met an issue as below. I followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47609029/veins-and-artery-throwing-errors-after-downgrading-omnet-back-to-5-1-1) to fix, but the solution was not mentioned.

Much appreciate,
Huy Nguyen.

[image: Invalid High Frequency CAM]

Comment: Have you made sure that SUMO is sending geo coordinates? For me, this looks like SUMO is sending X,Y coordinates which are not in the usual range of longitude and latitude

Comment: Hello Ventu, I just checked the coordinates in SUMO (on the lower right corner of SUMO) and it gave me N/A right the moment it crashed. I am not sure if that is supposed to happen. If indeed SUMO didn't send the correct coordinates, should I reinstall SUMO. The way I install it was via "sudo apt-get install sumo sumo-tools sumo-doc"

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the way to fix the issue. Earlier, I downloaded SUMo with the old version that comes with Ubuntu 20.04
(by `sumo apt-get install sumo sumo-tools sumo-docs` only)
I fixed the issue by downloading the newest version of SUMO:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:sumo/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sumo sumo-tools sumo-doc
```

Thank you @Ventu for your help.